# Consulta sobre la estructura de Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, singleton

Estimados estoy desarrollando un plan de cuenta y estoy utilizando una base de datos no relacional (espero no haberme equivocado), y necesito hacer que con firebase pueda crear un plan de cuenta.
Ademas de Firebase estoy utilizando Vuejs, pero en el momento de crear la estructura:

```
{
  "Activo": {
    "Sub cuenta de activo": {
      "nombre": ""
      },"Sub cuenta de activo 2": { ""},.....
    }

  },
  "Pasivo": {
    "Sub cuenta de pasivo": {
      "nombre": ""
      },"Sub cuenta de pasivo 2": { ""},.....
    }

  }
}
```

Y asi (Sub cuenta de activo 3..etc), seguir creando infinitamente sub cuentas de activos o pasivos. 
Para ello creo que necesito saber como crear o agregarle .chield() a la url de referncia para realizar el correspodiente push() asociado al ID de la "tabla" o objeto.
Estuve buscando miles de forma pero siempre llego al mismo problema, tener que agregar de forma manual la url de refencia.
Para pasar en limpio, quiera saber como crear un metodo en Vuejs donde pueda agregar .chield() de forma automatica sin hacerlo manual manualmente.
POr ejemplo aplicando el patron de desarrollo singleton.

Comment: Hola Nahuel, estas usando la Realtime Database o la Cloud Firestore? ambas son bases de datos no relacionales que provee firebase y tienen distinta estructura de datos. Y a que te referis con no hacerlo manualmente? podrias poner un ejemplo de lo que encontraste y no te gusto? eso ayudaria a entender lo que estas buscando

Comment: Hola @ErickSilva gracias por tu respuesta! Estaba usando Realtime, pero creo que tengo usar Firestore de acuerdo al modelo que quiero estructurar y las query's que deberia ejecutar. Cuando digo "manualmente", es cuando necesitas realizar algun cambio  tienes que saber la ubicacion exacta de  la rerefencia, es decir crear un metodo o alguna constante que almacene la refencia y eso no se hace de forma automatica agregarndo .chield() necesario hasta la ubicacion exacta (creo que no hay forma).

Answer (score 0):

si entiendo bien la estructura es una lista de cuentas pasivas y activas. Donde pones "sub cuenta de pasivo.." podría ser la clave mediante un push de firebase. Con tener una referencia a la base de datos  en "pasivo" y otra en "Activo" no tendrías que tener problema para agregar más cuentas. Solo tener que hacer "FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference('Pasivo').push().setValue(new CuentaPasivi()) ;“ y luego para obtener las cuentas solo creas un listener en la referencia Pasivo y recorres en un for cada cuenta o utilizas ChildEventListener. O puedes ordenar por algún nodo hijo y obtener alguna particular. Si es una cuenta por usuario podrías usar el uid del usuario como clave de su cuenta, si puede tener varias cuentas con el Push te creará claves distintas para cada entrada. Espero que sea esto lo que estabas buscando! saludos.